# Ansible Hosts looped within the playbook

Tags: loops, ansible, cisco

I have recently been using the open_excel module to contain all my variable data for a Cisco ACI  lab deployment. So far this works really well mainly due to the fact that all the Cisco ACI modules use the host: field within them as per below which means I can easily loop through the play from my data source.

```
  - name: "Add a new tenant"
    aci_tenant:
      host: "{{ apic }}"
      username: "{{ apic_username }}"
      password: "{{ apic_password }}"
      validate_certs: no
      tenant: "{{ tenants.tenant }}"
      description: "{{ tenants.description }}"
      state: "{{ tenants.state }}"
    delegate_to: localhost


    loop: "{{ tenants.sheet_index_0 }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: tenants
```

The problem I have is that I want to use this same approach for configuring other devices such as routers and switches but keeping all the host data in the spreadsheet rather than in individual host files.

Unfortunately the hosts are referenced at the top of the playbooks eg

```
---
- hosts: switches
```

and not under the tasks meaning I cant loop through different devices with different configuration s eg switch-1, vlans 2,3 switch-2, vlans 3,4 etc like I can with ACI.

Ideally I would want something like the following

```
- name: Configure VLANs on switches.
  nxos_vlans:
    host: "{{ vlans.switch }}"
    username: "{{ switch_username }}"
    password: "{{ switch_password }}"
    config:
      - vlan_id: " {{ vlans.vlan_id }} "
        name: " {{ vlans.vlan_name }} "
        state: " {{ vlans.vlan_state }} "


    loop: "{{ vlans }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: vlans
```

I'm still a bit of a beginner with Ansible and coding in general but if anyone has any suggestions that would be great.

FYI I think this same problem happens even if I was using read_csv.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same file always but implement the change on different hosts you can set your `hosts: all` and then implement the changes based on the hosts file, you can define for each host type a role and include it dynamically or import it. What I mean is something as follows:

hosts.yaml:

```
all:
  vars:
#    ansible_connection: network_cli
#    ansible_python_interpreter: ~/VENV/ansible/bin/python
    ansible_user: user


  children:
    aci:
      hosts:
        apic: 
          ansible_host: apic.example.com
    
    nxos:
      hosts:
        testsw01: 
          ansible_host: testsw01.example.com
        testsw02:
          ansible_host: testsw02.example.com
```

myplay.yaml:

```
- name: Test Play
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - include_role:
     name: TESTLAB_APIC
    when: "'apic' in inventory_hostname_short" #you can also use group_names here but you must change the keyword to aci

  - include_role:
     name: TESTLAB_NXOS
    when: "'nxos' in group_names"
```

you can create the following structure if you want:

```
└───roles
    ├───TESTLAB_APIC
    │   └───tasks
    │       │   main.yml
    │       │
    │       └───add_vlan
    │               add_vlan_to_apic.yml
    │
    ├───TESTLAB_NXOS
    │   └───tasks
    │       │   main.yml
    │       │
    │       └───add_vlan
    │               add_vlan_to_nxos_sw.yml
```

if you want in the roles you can address individual host in main.yaml file:
(main.yaml under the TESTLAB_APIC folder)

```
---
- include_tasks: add_vlan/add_vlan_to_apic.yml
  when: "'apic' in inventory_hostname_short"
...
```

(main.yml under the TESTLAB_NXOS folder)

```
---
- import_tasks: add_vlan/add_vlan_to_nxos_sw.yml
  when: when: "'testsw01' in inventory_hostname_short"
...
```

Of course, you need to write two separate .yml file for each type of switch/controller. For above examples are
`add_vlan/add_vlan_to_apic.yml`
and
`add_vlan/add_vlan_to_nxos_sw.yml`

Comment: Additionally, you can set the gather_facts: True and dynamically include the role/task by using "ansible_network_os" var